# How to signing digital signature for macos app bundle and linux executable

Tags: linux, digital-signature

I have an java swing application and building executable for three platform Window (exe), macOS(.app) an linux(.sh). I also have a .p12 file and need to signed for three platform executable.

I have signed for exe file on windows by `osslsigncode` and can check as digital signature tab in properties of exe file.

Now, I facing with problem that is i don't know how to sign a .p12 file to macOS executable(.app) and linux executable(.sh).

I also confuse that can we sign the .p12 file to macOS and Linux executable on linux build server like windows digital signature?

I have used linux build server to build executable for three platform

I also try with `openssl` command as:

```
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey MyFile.p12 -passin pass:mypass > /path/to/my/sh/file
```

but getting an error :unable to load Private Key

Is there any suggest for me?

Thanks all.

Happy coding ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can extract the private key form the .p12 (pfx) with this command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -nocerts -out key.pem
```

then you can sign your file

```
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey key.pem -in yourfile -out sigfile
```

and verify with

```
openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem -sigfile sigfile -in yourfile
```

but instead of using the actual file, you should sign / verify a checksum, so its better to use

```
sha512sum yourfile | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey yourkey -out sigfile
sha512sum yourfile | openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem -sigfile sigfile
```

Comment: I only have .p12 file and password of this certificate file. what I need is sign this file to executable of various platform with .p12 file and make it as signing with identified developer. 

In your suggest command 

`openssl rsautl -sign -inkey yourkey < yourfile > sigfile`

 I saw that have three parameter: 

`yourkey`: is that .pem file? I need convert my p12 to .pem file? 

`yourfile`: my executable file? 

`sigfile`: my p12 file?

Comment: < ... > ... are not parameters, its redirection, the command takes
'yourfile' (what you want to sign) as input and outputs 'sigfile'
(the signature file), see my edits